# Acceder a State desde archivo js en vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue3

estoy intentando acceder al store de vueX en Vue 3 desde un archivo .js que es auxiliar de un componente, sin embargo me devuelve undefined constantemente, he probado a usar los hooks de Vue, pero es imposible.

Necesito un parámetro que esta en el state para atender una petición a una api, desde un archivo js que se llama desde la vista.

```
 import { onMounted} from 'vue';
import { useStore } from 'vuex';

const store=useStore();

onMounted(()=>console.log(store));
```

¿Es posible hacer esta tarea desde un archivo .js?

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verifique que la exportación del modulo sea nombrada y no por default, porque sí es posible importar directamente, entonces siga:

**Js:**

```
import { useStore } from "../suStore";
console.log(store.state.myEstado) //Getter etc
```